# HTML change photo name after user takes photo

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to change the filename of a photo after the user takes a picture with a mobile device? In the code below, the `photoTaken()` function taken reads the information of the image and then calls the `uploadFile()` function. Is it possible to rename the file before it is sent to the server for processing?

HTML:

Javascript:

```
function photoTaken() {
    var count = document.getElementById('inp_file').files.length;
    //document.getElementById('PhotoList').innerHTML = "";
    for (var index = 0; index < count; index ++)
    {
        var file = document.getElementById('inp_file').files[index];
        var fileSize = 0;
        if (file.size > 1024 * 1024) {
            fileSize = (Math.round(file.size * 100 / (1024 * 1024)) / 100).toString() + 'MB';
        }
        else {
            fileSize = (Math.round(file.size * 100 / 1024) / 100).toString() + 'KB';
        }
        document.getElementById('PhotoList').innerHTML += file.name + '|' + fileSize;
        //document.getElementById('PhotoList').innerHTML += '<p>';
```

uploadFile();
          }

```
function uploadFile() {
    var fd = new FormData();
    var count = document.getElementById('inp_file').files.length;
    for (var index = 0; index < count; index ++) { 
        var file = document.getElementById('inp_file').files[index];
        fd.append(file.name, file);
    }
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);
    xhr.open("POST", "savetofile.aspx");
    xhr.send(fd);
}
```

Comment: sure, just alter `file.name` to pass-in whatever you want it to be

Comment: @Peter Sun  I would like to know what is the reason to rename the file on the front end?